# Importing data and time objects without time zones in R

Tags: r

I importing a CVS file which has dates and times in the below format.

```
date<-c("2017-04-17", "2017-04-18", "2017-04-19" )
times<-c( "23:45","0:00","17:00")
```

I would like to create a date and time object which has a different time zone than my system time.

```
parse_date_time(paste(temp1$Date, temp1$variable, sep=" "), orders = "%Y-m/%d %H:%M")
```

Now assume the time zone isn't UTC but UTC-6 or EST when being imported and I would like to convert it to another timezone. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From the `lubridate` package:

```
> library(lubridate)
> date<-c("2017-04-17", "2017-04-18", "2017-04-19" )
> times<-c( "23:45","0:00","17:00")
> paste(date, times)
[1] "2017-04-17 23:45" "2017-04-18 0:00"  "2017-04-19 17:00"
> ymd_hm(paste(date, times))
[1] "2017-04-17 23:45:00 UTC" "2017-04-18 00:00:00 UTC" "2017-04-19 17:00:00 UTC"
> ymd_hm(paste(date, times), tz="EST")
[1] "2017-04-17 23:45:00 EST" "2017-04-18 00:00:00 EST" "2017-04-19 17:00:00 EST"
```